# Date.now() returns a value in microseconds and not in milliseconds

Tags: javascript, browser

`Date.now()`, as per the documentation is supposed to return a Unix timestamp or the Epoch Time, that is, the number of *milliseconds* that have lapsed since 1st January 1970.

The current unix timestamp as per this website (or any other valid means of computation) is approximately 1554637184. Note that there are 10 digits in this value. This value is actually in milliseconds.

However, the value returned by `Date.now()` in all the three browsers -- Chrome 73, Firefox 66.0.2 and Edge 17.17134 -- is 1554637694364, which is observed to be of 13 digits, and therefore, I infer it is the number of *microseconds* that have elapsed since 1st January 1970.

What's going on?

I just realized this after years of using it because just now I was debugging some code that made a check like so that failed:

```
let endTime = ...; // a time later than now expressed as a unix timestamp
let now = Date.now();

if (endTime <= now) {
  // And it always came here, and that led me to this discovery
  ...
}
```

Comment: What JavaScript implementation is this?

Comment: @ChaosPandion It reports that value on the 3 browsers I am testing on -- Firefox, Chrome and Edge. I have updated the question with the version numbers.

Comment: `This value is actually in milliseconds.` no, it is seconds, as per any documentation you care to read about unix timestamp ... `I infer it is the number of microseconds` you infer incorrectly ... there have been `1554637694364ms` since 1970

Comment: Simple manual calculation reveals that 1554637694364ms is about 49 years. Which sounds about right.

Comment: 49.26349577800594 years to be precise @mbojko :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current epoch time (AKA unix timestamp), `1554637856` is the number of ***seconds*** since 01-01-1970, not milliseconds.

`Date.now()` returns the epoch time in ***milli**seconds*, so you'd want seconds:

```
if (endTime <= now / 1000) {
...
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing the confusion. It's a little thing I might have mixed up over time. A few more minutes until I can mark your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing the time *in seconds* since the UNIX epoch is about `1 554 637 931`. So, the time in milliseconds—the JavaScript time—is about `1 554 637 931 654`.

It’s been about 1.55 gigaseconds since the epoch. Your JavaScript timestamps are, in fact, milliseconds.